# How do I raise a custom exception from a package __init__?

Tags: python

I have a package `__init__.py` that looks something like this:

```
import sys

__required_python_version = (2,6, 0)

if sys.version_info < __required_python_version:
    this_version = '.'.join([str(x) for x in sys.version_info[0:3]])
    required_version = '.'.join([str(x) for x in __required_python_version])
    raise PythonVersionError(this_version, required_version)

class PythonVersionError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, this_version, required_version):
        self.this_version = this_version
        self.required_version = required_version

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Python version %s is invalid.  Must be at least %s' % (self.this_ver, self.required_ver)
```

While I'm certain there is a more elegant way to format those version strings and I could probably get by using a standard exception, my real question is how would I do something like this?  Would the best approach be to move my custom exception into a separate file and import it?  Or should I wrap the version check in a function that executes when the `__init__` is run?  I'm just looking for recommendations on the preferred approach.

Thanks

Comment: Oops, my underscores around init turned into markup.  I guess I need to learn how to escape characters on here.

Comment: Highlight the text you want to make into code and press the "code" button on the toolbar. It will surround it with a blank line and indent it 4 spaces.  You'll also want to use backticks around `inline code`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: use the code tag when writing code to prevent that from happening

Comment: I fixed your formatting; have a look ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Although I think I'm a little unnerved that other people can edit my posts.  Interesting

Comment: @zenzic: only people with sufficient reputation can edit posts.

Answer (score 3):

Since it looks like you won't have any user for that exception -- 
unless this module is to be used by other modules you are impleemnting as part of a larger system, I say you don't need a custom exception here.

There is very little to gain from it, apart from the error message given. Ay module trying to import yours would have to be aware of it, to catch the exception, or just let the program stop witha  backtrace. Since be aware of it , it would need to import your module, it would just crash to a backtrace anyway -- wher ethe user can then read the error message.

For one to read the error message,a plain "Exception" stating it is the incorrect PythonVersin is as good as any custom exception.

On the technical side, Python would need to know about  `PythonVersionError` before raising it: you need to put that code before you try to raise it inside the `if` block.

And finally, if you *are* building a larger system, and other parts of the system might try to catch `PythonVersionError`, the coorect thing to do is to put it in its own file/module, so that it becomes available to this module that will raise it, and any other modules that are importing this.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something awkward here.

Is it really usefull to create a custom Exception class when it won't be reused anywhere else in other modules ? If everyone did this we would end up with every module defining it's own different (and probably incompatible) PythonVersionError class.

Why don't you use a standard existing exception ? For this one I would probably go for a standard RuntimeError exception.

OK, I know you don't want this answer, but anyway.

If I really wanted to do this at least I would define PythonVersionException class as a local instance of checking code to avoid polluting module namespace or any global namespace of other files of the module.

Comment: I agree and that's what I ultimately did, even though I didn't find a standard exception class that I thought was a great fit.  But like I said in the original post, that left me with the above question of how one _would_ do something like this if it were really needed.

Comment: @zenzic: I completed my answer. That's just the way I would do it.